# How to change the directory path and create an empty file in PHP run file on Ubuntu

Tags: php, linux

Here is my code where I mention the file; the file is located in `/var/www/wpscan/log.txt` and the PHP code runs in `/var/www/html/form/index.php` where I write my logic.

When I run the file it displays the error "Unable to open file!".

```
$url = $_POST['url'];
$from_email = $_POST['email'];
$newdate=date('Y-m-d');
chdir('/var/www/wpscan/');
// current directory
$abc= getcwd();
$filepermission=$abc. '/log.txt';
$myfile = fopen( '/var/www/wpscan/log.txt', "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$shelltest=shell_exec('ls');
fwrite($myfile, $shelltest);

fclose($myfile);
```

Comment: Are you sure your application (PHP user) has rights to edit the `log.txt` file? Furthermore, if using SELinux it is often required that a file have context `HTTPD_SYS_RW_CONTENT_T` to be editable by `httpd`

Comment: Most likely the file permissions are insufficient for a php script to read the file.

Comment: @santy The file is being opened for writing I think.

Comment: Also, not really sure why you're trying to change your working directory. That's definitely not necessary to do any of this.

Comment: Whether you open to append, read or write, the Linux file permissions need to be correct in order, for the user where PHP is running from, to access the file.

Comment: yes i given the folder permission as 665 it can't create and read file

Answer (score 1):

First:

```
sudo chmod 777 /var/www/wpscan/log.txt
```

Next:

```
$url = $_POST['url'];
$from_email = $_POST['email'];
$newdate=date('Y-m-d');
chdir('/var/www/wpscan/');
// current directory
$abc= getcwd();
$filepermission=$abc. '/log.txt';
$myfile = fopen($filepermission, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$shelltest=shell_exec('ls');
fwrite($myfile, $shelltest);

fclose($myfile);
```